# Publishing concepts

Tags: tridion, publishing, tridion-2011

I have some basic questions related to publishing.
If I have a component A which has a multimedia link to Component B.
When I publish component A using a dynamic CT, the component B will also be published.

1. Will component B's custom meta-data also get published? (I couldn't locate the custom meta-data in transport package for component B)
2. If I unpublish component A, It will also unpublish component B? But what if component B is linked and published with several other components?
3. If I insert a component on a page using a dynamic CT, after publishing, will the component Presentation get added to database, or as a static part on page or at both locations? (We use file system for pages and broker DB for dynamic CPs)

I know these are basic questions, but these will solve several doubts. thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify if you have a dynamic CT associated with the Schema used by Component B?

Comment: You might want to read the first two sections of this article that explain many details about how Tridion publishes binaries: http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/binaryeventtracker.aspx

Comment: @ChrisSummers : Yes, we do have a dynamic CT. 
Thanks Frank...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If I have a component A which has a multimedia link to Component B. When I publish component A using a dynamic CT, the component B will also be published.**

This is not true. To publish multimedia links you have to use `<img src="tcmid" ..... />` for your multimedia link to be published and your CT needs to include `Default Finish Actions` which contains `Publish Binaries in package`.

Typically When you publish Component A, it will only publish multimedia file (img,jpg,pdf etc) when you have above line of code in your DWT and you have the TBBs mentioned above.

**Q # 1 :** In this case metadata will not be published since you are just publishing the multimedia file via code

**Q # 2 :** Multimedia File will not unpublished when you unpublish Component A if it is being used or referenced. Tridion Deployer checks if there are any references to the multimedia file and deletes the file only if it does not have any references.

**Q # 3 :** Publishing to databasse or filesystem is not just based on simply Dynamic CT. It is based on your storage configuration on your deployer side. It based on what you configure in the storage either to db DB or FS.

If you want to publish Multimedia Components dynamically you need a Dynamic CT associated with that Multimedia Schema (OR) You could write a C# TBB as part of your Dynamic CT of the same for Component A and publish dynamically via code.

Here is Tridion documentation you can also check, may not be straight forward answers to your questions, but will provide some additional information.

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_56BCD7B2A1994C76B940751B2458D8E0